# Returning all tables value from database in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get record against unique id from database but i am getting all the record i have 2 columns in my table and i am getting all the 2 but only want is to get 1 in my view.

My View in which i am using blade template:

```
<li><a href="{{url('Template'.($value->particulars1)->template)}}" class="viewpage" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Page</a></li>
```

Here i am getting record based on template id as u can see $value->particulars1)->template but it is returning all 2 tables i somehow also
want to get record against id(which is auto incrementing) but i am unable to get my records

My Controller:

```
public function Template1()
{
    $template1 = Sale::all();
    return view('Template-1',compact('template1'));
}
```

and my router:

```
$router->get('/Template1', 'AjaxController@Template1');
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the dump of **$template1**.

Comment: i already did and i am getting 2 records and only 2 records exists!

Comment: i am getting 2 records in my view but i only want 1 against auto increment id

Comment: Yes. But it will help us to help you :). please show the dump.

Comment: its like ject(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#141 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(App\Sale)#138 (26) { ["table":protected]=> string(16) "page_particulars" ["fillable":protected]=> array(15) { [0]=> string(7) "user_id" [1]=> string(12) "product_asin" [2]=> string(16) "page_expiry_date" [3]=> string(14) "list_reference" [4]=> string(11) "promo_title" [5]=> string(13) "regular_price" [6]=> string(11) "promo_price" [7]=> string(12) "company_logo" [8]=> strin

Comment: and goes on.....

Comment: and when i  echo '<pre>';
        echo (count($template1));  it show 2 means 2 records

Comment: " i only want 1 against auto increment id" what is the meaning of against auto increment id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169074/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-shahzad1122).

Answer (score 1):

Change your link,

```
<li><a href="{{url('template/'.($value->particulars1)->template)}}" class="viewpage" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Page</a></li>
```

Change this function,

```
public function Template1($id)
  {
    $template1 = Sale::find($id);
    return view('Template-1',compact('template1'));
  }
```

Change this route,

```
$router->get('/template/{id}', 'AjaxController@Template1');
```